# Understanding how $.proxy works internally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Was just going through the source code of jQuery $.proxy , and came across the following lines of code , see below:

```
if (typeof context === "string") {
        tmp = fn[context];
        context = fn;
        fn = tmp;
    }
```

The entire function code can be seen **[HERE](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.proxy)**, what i want to know is , what is the above code provision for , I.E. when does the above code come into play ? can anybody explain ? I totally understand what the code is doing but , what i would like to know is a real code situation in which such a piece of code would be useful.

EDIT::

The entire function code can be seen below:

```
function (fn, context) {
    var args, proxy, tmp;

    if (typeof context === "string") {
        tmp = fn[context];
        context = fn;
        fn = tmp;
    }

    // Quick check to determine if target is callable, in the spec
    // this throws a TypeError, but we will just return undefined.
    if (!jQuery.isFunction(fn)) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // Simulated bind
    args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    proxy = function () {
        return fn.apply(context || this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };

    // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
    proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++;

    return proxy;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So do you understand what $.proxy does? or what?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why they thought they had to implement a `(context, name)` signature. I find it very misleading  and frankly quite useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to understand the purpose of [$.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) but wondering when it can be useful to be able to pass a string as a "context"? Well, the way I see it is mostly a matter of preference really, because both signatures can be used interchangeably.

Here is the typical usage of the $.proxy (or [Funtion.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

```js
var user = {
    username: 'Thomas Mann',
    getUsername: function() {
        alert(this.username);
    }
};

$('button').click($.proxy(user.getUsername, user));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Check</button>
```

Nothing special. However, jQuery proxy implementation allows you to swap base object and context, so above example could also be rewritten as follows:

```js
var user = {
    username: 'Thomas Mann',
    getUsername: function() {
        alert(this.username);
    }
};

$('button').click($.proxy(user, 'getUsername'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Check</button>
```

So in this case you pass *context first* and then method name to call on the context object.

Note however, that classical [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) follows the first notation. I recommend to do the same for consistency. I also haven't seen anyone using it the second way so better to avoid this not very clear syntax.

Comment: so the only and soly purpose of the lines of code i highlighted , is to accommodate , cases like the secound example you provided ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Yes, so that you could pass context first and then method name. But as I said I would stick to the first use case which is more familiar to most developers (because it mimics native bind method).